# React router dom layout hides content

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a project using react-router-dom, and I can't achieve to have a route in which I have a lateral menu.

I need my lateral menu to be available on each `/users/:id` routes, so I can navigate between differents informations about the current user.

This is what I came to :

```
            <Route path=":id" element={<UserLayout />}>
              <Route
                index
                element={
                  isLoading ? (
                    ""
                  ) : hasPermissionToRoute("/users/:id/") ? (
                    <User />
                  ) : (
                    <AccessForbidden />
                  )
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="contracts"
                element={
                  isLoading ? (
                    ""
                  ) : hasPermissionToRoute("/users/:id/contracts") ? (
                    "contracts"
                  ) : (
                    <AccessForbidden />
                  )
                }
              />
            </Route>
```

And `<UserLayout />` being :

```
export function UserLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className="flex gap-5">
      <div>menu</div>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I go to `/users/id/` I only got menu displayed, same for `/users/id/contracts`. The problem is not coming from the conditions of the subroutes since when I delete `element={<UserLayout />}` it works properly (but without the lateral menu).

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: You are maybe missing the crucial `Outlet` component from React Router on your parent  `UserLayout` component. `Outlet` component renders the matching child route with its respective component (here `User` component) from the parent Routes' component collection of Route components. source: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-nested-routes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `Outlet` component on your `UserLayout` component. `Outlet` component renders the matching child route with its respective component (here `User`)

```js
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export function UserLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className="flex gap-5">
      <div>menu</div>
      <Outlet/>
    </div>
  );
}
```